# How to run a analyze query using java-jdbc program?

Tags: postgresql, scala, jdbc

I am trying to run an analyze query on a scala jdbc program as mentioned below.

```
try {
    for(t<-tabList){
        var statement = con.prepareStatement(s"analyze ${t}")
        println(s"Analyze for: ${t}")
        val rs = statement.execute()
        println(s"Analyze completed for the table: ${t}")
        println(rs)
    }
} catch {
    case pse:PSQLException => pse.printStackTrace()
    case e:Exception       => e.printStackTrace()
}
```

The table is on postgres and I am creating jar of my program and running it from command line as give below.

```
scala -cp /home/username/postgresql-42.1.4.jar analyzetables_2.11-0.1.jar schema.tablename
```

The code doesn't give any errors but I see the result from resultset object as false as below:

```
Analyze for: schema.tablename
Analyze completed for the table: schema.tablename
false
```

The query doesn't fail hence no exception during run time. Also the tables given are present in the database and they contain data. But I printed the resultset object and see that the boolean value `false`.
Does this mean the analyze query is failed or should I run this in any other way ?
Could let me know if there is any problem with the way I handled the "analyze" query and is there a better or right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ANALYZE` does not produce any result set.

If you get no `java.sql.SQLException`, you can assume that it worked.

You should use `executeUpdate()` rather than `execute()`, and it would be better to take a `java.sql.Statement` rather than a `java.sql.PreparedStatement` in the first place.